# PHP Doctrine connect to MSSQL server v11 drops auth exception

Tags: php, sql-server, authentication, doctrine

I want to connect an MS-SQL server v11.0.7001.0 using Doctrine. The user I have to use exists on the SQL server as user with "SQL Authentication".

What I do is:

```
$modelPath = __DIR__."/../model";
$config = ORMSetup::createAttributeMetadataConfiguration(
    paths: array($modelPath),
    isDevMode: true,
);

$conn = array(
    'driver'   => "pdo_sqlsrv",
    'host'     => "sqlserver1",
    'user'     => "myUser",
    'password' => "fancyPwdHere123",
    'dbname'   => "testDatabase",
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

The result is is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000]: 
  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUser'. 
  in E:\PHP\Doctrine-ORM\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\SQLSrv\Driver.php:42
    Stack trace:
    #0 E:\PHP\Doctrine-ORM\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\SQLSrv\Driver.php(42): PDO->__construct()
    #1 E:\PHP\Doctrine-ORM\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Connection.php(346): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\SQLSrv\Driver->connect()
    #2 E:\PHP\Doctrine-ORM\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Connection.php(1619): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
    #3 E:\PHP\Doctrine-ORM\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Connection.php(1013): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getWrappedConnection()
    #4 E:\PHP\Doctrine-ORM\tryIt.php(7): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->prepare()
    #5 {main}
```

The user name and password is good (double checked). My PHP is 8.1.11, and composer.json content is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.11.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.4",
        "symfony/cache": "^5.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

Any advice why this happens and how to resolve the login problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the actual authentication error in the SQL Server Logs. The authentication error passed to the application layer is intentionally ambiguous. If you don't understand that error, then [edit] your question to include that error. *(I also assume you mean v11.0.7001, as there was no v11.0.700; the lowest version number of SQL Server 2012 was 11.0.1103.9, which was CTP1.)*

Comment: My mistake, sorry, 11.0.7001.0 is the correct sql version number.

Comment: With the help of the DB admin I checked the server log as you suggested, and found that the user cannot access the given database for some reason. Now it seems the login is correct. Now I have other error :) But this seems to be resolved! Thanks for you time and help!

Comment: Generally speaking (ignoring contained databases) logins get you access at the server level, you still need to create users at the database level and map them to logins. Ask your DBA to check the user in the related database.